# XQuery - Terse equivalent to "let $a := foo(); if($a) then $a else 'default'"

Tags: xquery

In Python, using the first "truthy" value of several candidates can be written in the form:

```
result = a or b or c
```

...which avoids any need for repetition or variable assignment when dealing with result of function calls:

```
result = get-candidate() or get-default()
```

Is a terse, performant, readable equivalent available in XQuery?

The best I can come up with (without relying on the engine to optimize multiple calls to `get-candidate()` down to one, which may not be possible at all if it does something like an external HTTP or SQL transaction) is something akin to the following:

```
let $a := get-candidate()
return if($a) then $a else get-default()
```

...particularly if this is being repeated a number of times, it's not very pretty.

What's the best terse, readable approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your candidate will either be a single item or an empty sequence, you can use the following notation:

`(get-candidate(), get-default())[1]`

Otherwise, you'll probably have to stick with the verbose representation.

Comment: Thanks, Christian! Does this short-circuit the call to `get-default()` if `get-candidate()` returns a result?

Comment: I actually think that's up to the implementation to descide, the spec allows both lazy (and thus short-circuiting) and eager evaluation strategies. In BaseX the construct is currently evaluated lazily, so `get-default()` won't be called.